# Fetch Http-Status-Codes in arduino (ESP8266)

Tags: arduino, http-status-codes, esp8266

I did go through ESP8266WiFi.h but not able to figure out how to retrieve [HTTP-status-codes](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml#http-status-codes-1) once I get a response.

My code is as follows:

```
String serverMessage = BuildOutMessage();
client.print(serverMessage);
delay(10);
```

...

```
while (client.available()){
    String line = client.readString();
    Serial.println(line);
}

Serial.println("");
Serial.println("closing connection");
```

There are no methods to obtain HTTP Status codes or the 200/404/400/etc. is not part of the message I get from the server. How can I retrieve the status code?

I did try using Postman and I see the status code.

Answer (score 1):

The status code is on the first line of the HTTP response (from the server to the client). An example response might be:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Connection: close

Some text here.
```

If you are writing client code then you should parse the first line of the response from the server, looking for that number. One method would be to gather the contents of that line into a char buffer, and then use `strtok` to break that up into groups separated by spaces.

Comment: That is what I expected when I do while (client.available()) and client.readString(). But I do not see HTTP/1.1 200 OK.

Comment: What *do* you see? Your code is flawed in that you expect an immediate response. I can't tell from your snippet, but if you send something, and immediately loop looking for a reply, and it hasn't arrived with a few microseconds, you will miss it.